# node-red loop through global variables

Tags: javascript, loops, node-red

Using node-red; 
I'm storing data in global variables. I'm using a guid as the identifier for the variable.
e.g:

```
global.set(msg.guid,{"watch":true, "command":msg.content, "custno":msg.custno, "result":msg.payload});
return msg;
```

In a separate flow I want to loop through all these variables to check the content and act accordingly.
I can't find a way to get to the global variables apart from:

```
global.get("theguid");
```

So I have to know all the guids, and I don't know the number of items.

I have some thoughts on how to approach this, but wondered if I'm missing something obvious!

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why not set a global that is the container for all guids and then access the container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a single top-level context object, rather than scatter your objects in the global namespace.

For example:

```
var myObjects = global.get("myObjects");
myObjects[msg.guid] = {"watch":true, "command":msg.content, "custno":msg.custno, "result":msg.payload};
global.set("myObjects",myObjects);
return msg;
```

You can then retrieve the `myObjects` object and use all the standard JavaScript functions for working with it:

```
var myObjects = global.get("myObjects");
var listOfGuids = Object.keys(myObject);
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you for writing out an example. I didn't have time to

Comment: Thanks for this useful and quick response Nick - I'd been trying to work through some of your other responses to piece this together. The .keys was the missing part of the puzzle for me! Thanks also Mike

Comment: @mhodges ah - didn't spot your comment when I started to write that.